# How to debug mobile QML applications in production?

Tags: qt, mobile, qml

1. If crash happened on mobile device, how developer team can receive it?
2. What should be logged to restore what happened? Just actions on objects and page transitions?
3. If my markup will looks wrong on some devices or application will behave strange or come to weird state, I want functionality to collect screenshot and info from device and send it. What is the best practices here?

Comment: Try to read your own question and understand what it says. I'm failed to do that. What a client? What a device? What a picture?

Answer (score 1):

The question is about sending the crash stack trace and logs out. Not about QML app per se but about its C++ base or just about C++ app if we have one. The app should have logging enabled and collect its activity info, maybe for the period of time or until the logs get large enough. We were splitting log  in chunks files and removing the oldest after we've accumulated, say, 5 of 100kb chunks.

Crash stack/minidump. Both call stack for all threads and the time of the crash plus minidump of the code with all variables visible can be collected.

How to send the log and crash stack/minidump out? There solutions like [BreakPad](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/minidump/breakpad/) we supposed to link with/ enable in the app code. The app will take care of sending all the crash info out when it runs again after the crash.

Quite a few things to implement, no to mention the web service that collects the crash info from client apps.

And you have to have "symbols" for the app release code kept in order to be able to trace the stack and see variable values at the time of a crash.